# Get sign of unassigned variables

Tags: display, number-representation, output-formatting

I want to find the signs of the following expression of unassigned variables:

```
a = x1 x2 - x3 x4;
```

The signs or prefactors are `+1` and `-1`, however only the `-` is displayed. I get the sign of the 2nd expression by

```
a[[2, 1]]
-1
```

For the first expression I get only

```
a[[1, 1]]
x1
```

`Sign[a[[1]]]`

or
forcing the `+` by

`NumberForm[a[[1]], NumberSigns -> {"-", "+"}]`

do not work.

Comment: ``Replace[(a /. Plus -> List), {-_ -> -1, _ -> 1}, 1]`` returns ``{1, -1}``.

Comment: The signs are returned, however if my indices are expressed by subscripts ```a = Subscript[x, 1] Subscript[x, 2] - Subscript[x, 3] Subscript[x, 4];```  then ```a``` becomes unusable. One could just use a copy of ```a``` but is there a way that does not change ```a```?

Comment: I don't quite understand your comment. What exactly do you mean by "``a`` becomes unusable"? Could you please provide your full example? Furthermore, in Mathematica it is generally advised against using variables written as subscripts.

Comment: If I use ```a``` as defined in the previous comment then ```Replace``` manipulates the structure of ```a```.

Comment: I would use upsets to "teach" mathematica the signs, e.g. `Sign[x1] ^= 1`. (For all at once: `Sign[#] ^= 1; & /@ {x1, x2, x3, x4};`.) Then `Sign[a[[1]]]` works, for instance. But is there an underlying problem you're trying to solve here? For example, `CoefficientRules[a, {x1, x2, x3, x4}]` gives you more robust information, which might or might not be useful depending on the situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
syntacticSign = (-1)^Boole[Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ @ #] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
a = x1 x2 - x3 x4;

syntacticSign /@ {a, a[[1]], a[[2]]}
```

> ```
> {1, 1, -1}
> ```

**Update:** *"to output all signs of an expression with one call without explicitely specifying all subterms"*:

```
syntacticSigns = Map[syntacticSign] @* MonomialList;

syntacticSigns @ a
```

> ```
> {1, -1}
> ```

Comment: could this be modified to output all signs of an expression with one call without explicitely specifying all subterms?

Comment: @granularbastard, please see the update.

Comment: @kglr Excellent solution!